# Explanation of inference rules with quantifiers

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm referring to the inference rules listed at this page of Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus), under the section of $LK$ system. There are four rules for the quantifiers; however we have restrictions only for $\forall R$ and $\exists L$. The motivations for $\forall R$ are clear, because in order to conclude that $\forall x A(x) \Rightarrow B$, one must prove that $A(t) \Rightarrow B$ for a generic $t$ (i.e. not a variable used before). However why one can't say the same for the rule $\forall L$?

Plus, in the case of $\exists L$ I'm not sure to understand why we have the restrictions, and anyway I don't understand why we have it only in one case. Eventually, can anyone tell me what book (or material in general) I could use to clarify these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this question self-contained, these are the rules in question:

$$\forall L: \frac{\Gamma, A[t/x] \vdash \Delta}{\Gamma, \forall x A \vdash \Delta}$$

$$\forall R: \frac{\Gamma \vdash A[y/x], \Delta}{\Gamma \vdash \forall x A, \Delta}$$

In the case of $\forall R$, you are trying to *conclude* $\forall x A$.  Therefore your assumption must be $A[y/x]$ where $y$ is a new variable, so that $y$ is a generic element, not a variable you have used before which may have some additional assumptions on it. Therefore there are restrictions necessary for $\forall R$.

However, in the case of $\forall L$, you start with $A[t/x] \Rightarrow \Delta$ and are trying to conclude $\forall x A \Rightarrow \Delta$. The $\forall x A$ appears as an *assumption*. Therefore no restriction is necessary, because you already know that $A$ holds for all $x$.  Therefore you can substitute *any* $t$ for $x$, and apply the original $A[t/x] \Rightarrow \Delta$ to conclude $\Delta$.

The situation for $\exists$ is similar.